# err Repo github:angular not found! [jspm install]

Tags: javascript, jspm

I am getting this error while doing jspm install,

`err  Repo github:angular not found!`

executing  `jsp install github:angular`  also doesnt work.

jspm_config.json location is
https://plnkr.co/edit/2svUSwjVgCxyJ4iJHj1T?p=info

Can someone please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue,

the local ~/.jspm/config file on mac has to be configured with correct url for github, I had initially configured to use `https://github.com` as jspm registry for github which was causing the issue,

I replaced that with `https://github.jspm.io` and removed any auth attribute. It asked me to generate the auth token and all went smooth.

```
"github": {
      "remote": "https://github.jspm.io",
      "auth": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "maxRepoSize": 0,
      "handler": "jspm-github"
    }
```

Comment: for windows 10 config file is present in `%LOCALAPPDATA%/.jspm/config`